# IWICDdsDecoder fails to load Cube maps

Tags: textures, direct3d11, wic, dds-format

I created a Texture Cube with [NVidia's Texture Exporter Tool](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-texture-tools-exporter) but I cannot load it with `IWICDdsDecoder`.

It fails with `0x88982f61 : The image header is unrecognized.`.

On the other hand, normal 2D textures (`Dimension = WICDdsTexture2D`) created with NVTET load correctly and work well.

Does `IWICDdsLoader` support Cube Maps and if not, why is the `WICDdsDimension.WICDdsTextureCube` specified?

Partial loader code that works for normal `WICDdsTexture2D` textures written by the NVTET.

```
HRESULT lResult;

WICStream lStream;
lResult = gFactory->CreateStream(&lStream);
if (FAILED(lResult)) return lResult;

lResult = lStream->InitializeFromFilename(aPath, GENERIC_READ);
if (FAILED(lResult)) return lResult;

WICBitmapDecoder lBitmapDecoder;
lResult = gFactory->CreateDecoder(GUID_ContainerFormatDds, nullptr, &lBitmapDecoder);
if (FAILED(lResult)) return lResult;

lResult = lBitmapDecoder->Initialize(lStream, WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnDemand);
if (FAILED(lResult)) return lResult; // <-- it fails here!
// 0x88982f61 : The image header is unrecognized.

WICDdsDecoder lDecoder(lBitmapDecoder);
if (!lDecoder) return E_NOINTERFACE;

WICDdsParameters lParameters{};
lResult = lDecoder->GetParameters(&lParameters);
if (FAILED(lResult)) return lResult;
if (lParameters.Dimension != WICDdsTextureCube) return E_FAIL;

// etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in WIC DDS codec introduced in Windows 8.1 is designed to support WebGL. It only supports DXT1-5 (BC1-3) format textures. This is documented on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/what-s-new-in-wic-for-windows-8-1#support-for-block-compressed-formats-dds-files).

For efficient loading of DDS files (all DXGI formats & complex surface constructs), take a look at `DDSTextureLoader` for [DX11](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/DDSTextureLoader) or [DX12](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/DDSTextureLoader). This module is available integrated into the *DirectX Tool Kit* and as standalone versions in the [DirectXTex](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTex/tree/master/DDSTextureLoader) project.

If you need support for legacy Direct3D 9 era format DDS files, format conversion, etc. see the [DirectXTex](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTex/wiki/DDS-I-O-Functions) DDS codec.

See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/direct3d-11-textures-and-block-compression/) for more background on modern DDS texture handling.

> There is also a Direct3D 9 version of `DDSTextureLoader` available if needed in the *DirectXTex* project. See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/directx-tool-kit-for-audio-updates-and-a-direct3d-9-footnote/) for details.

Comment: I ended up using your code. And no legacy support needed. My DDS-es are written with my custom **texconv** tool *(where I added the -ip flag that you didn't accept)* or NVidia Tool Texture Cubes.

Comment: DDSTextureLoader is definitely the way to go then.

Comment: BTW I'm down to just 8 bits of my 64-bit options quad-word in ``texconv`` so I need to be careful about new command-line options for that tool or I'll need to work the whole options system. I have already merged a few seldom-used options to recover a few bits, and I have some variants that use a few bits as well.

Comment: The code does show that it's "built on the fly". :)